# Deploy Active Directory and ADFS 2.0 in Azure Virtual Machine

Tags: active-directory, azure, adfs

Is it possible to use an Azure virtual machine as an Active Directory server with ADFS 2.0 and integrate it with ACS ?

Regards ,

James Roeiter

Comment: I havent done it myself. But I'd guess it is. http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2012/SIA205 is a session worth checking out for the AD portion at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently virtual machines in Azure are a preview feature , when they will be available it will be possible to install your own services (such as AD) and use them for your systems.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution for current state until virtual machines will be officially available in Azure- I created account in one of many dedicated servers providers and created an ADFS server there , then integrated that server with Azure.
ADFS can be easily clustered and also can be easily integrated with Azure service bus so its a redundant solution.

Regards ,

James Roeiter